# Action Button not showing in Action Bar

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, icons, action

`ActionBar` not showing icons for items. This is my menu xml so far. It just shows the action overflow with stuff in the action overflow.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please refer this link for complete details http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code with the following and try again;

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```

Also make sure that you have the following part;

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Android Studio underlined android:showAsAction="always" so I didn't put it in.
Adding it solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

1) using android default action bar

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
 </menu>
```

2) if using supported action bar

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always">
 </menu>
```

For more information you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) .

Answer (score 0):

use java code at onCreate() or onStart()

```
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

or

```
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

and check you have set a icon at application, such as

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
....
/>
```

at last, why you use yourapp:showAsAction="always" , android:showAsAction="always" is also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add below code to your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```